# Git local file overridden

Tags: git

I'm new to Git and am just after overriding local files that took me hours to complete. If anyone could help me restore them (if that's even possible!!) I would be very appreciative. Heres a list of my commands.

```
git add --all
git commit -m 'Memento'
git checkout master
git push origin master #(ERROR)(TELLS ME MY CURRENT BRANCH IS BEHIND)
git checkout enemies
git commit -m 'Memento'
git push origin enemies #(ERROR)(TELLS ME TO PULL)
git pull
git push origin enemies #(ERROR)(TELLS ME MY CURRENT BRANCH IS BEHIND)
git branch memento
git checkout memento
git push origin memento
git add --all
git commit -m 'memento'
git push origin memento
```

Sorry for the lack of cohesion with my commands, I'm a complete beginner and was blind to the fact it could mess with my local files.

Comment: You have not mentioned what was your branch when you started with. When you checkout a different branch and if it has remote changes, you need to also pull them before you push.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Type in

```
$ git reflog
```

Find the step that you want to rollback to. For example if you know that at `HEAD@{12}` everything was still ok, you do

```
$ git reset --hard HEAD@{12}
```

Rule of thumb if you're new to Git: don't execute any commands unless you know the consequences.
I learned this the hard way myself.

Answer (score 0):

Because you appear to have committed your changes to `git`, the old commits should be in the `git reflog` (assuming this happened less than a few days ago).

`git reflog` shows you the commits that your repository has gone through. It shows you the git commit ID for each of the historical entries. You can then use `git reset --hard <commit ID>` to restore your repository to a specific state (make sure to commit uncommitted work first!)

Answer (score 0):

Just some strange bugs i'd like to point out to you guys.

Doing as stated above fixed most issues however two packages were now empty. They contained no classes when there had been 3/4 classes in them before this issue.

I tried deleting the package and each time it would tell me 'out of sync' or something similiar and then repopulate my package with one class. I had to continue to 'delete' my package 3/4 times until it was completly repopulated.
Strange but everything is working now,

Thanks again